# Deploy cloud-formation from on-Premise Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-cli

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline which will deploy a cloudformation template to AWS.I thought of using AWS CLI from jenkins to deploy the template.

My pipeline looks like below

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('hello AWS') {
        steps {
            withAWS(role:'Jenkins', roleAccount:'XXXX8216610',duration: 
            900, roleSessionName: 'jenkins-session') {

                sh 'aws cloudformation deploy --template-file 
              /path_to_template/template.json --stack-name my-new-stack '
```

But here the problem is my Jenkins is on-Premise so i just cannot simply create and attach AWS role to deploy the template.Also i cannot use credentials/access keys of users in my job.So which other ways i can achieve this ?

Comment: Why can't you use user credentials in your pipeline?

Comment: @WarrenG Shops standard does not allow that.According to them its not good practice.

Comment: It isn't best practice, but you will need a user in your case. You should however limit the user's rights and make use of temporary tokens to authenticate (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-federation-token.html). The user you should create should also not have an console access. So while there is not much you can do to get around using user credentials, you can reduce the risks by making use of assume roles.

Comment: @WarrenG Thanks !! Do you have any example to do this using assume role ?